# android drawing lines on horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, drawing, scrollview, lines

hello i have released my iphone app Micro-Pitch and am now porting it to android. I cannot figure out how to draw lines in a scroll view and am wondering what i am doing wrong.

here is the part of my interface with the scroll view

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll_view" android:layout_above="@+id/btn_info" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:overScrollMode="always" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/scroll_layout" android:layout_width="match_parent">
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

this is my plot_view class

```
public class PlotView extends View
{
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public PlotView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(20, 0, 0, 20, paint);
    }
}
```

and this is the segment of my main activity class

```
HorizontalScrollView scroll_view;
LinearLayout scroll_layout;
PlotView plot_view;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    scroll_view= (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
    scroll_layout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scroll_layout);

    plot_view = new PlotView(this);
    plot_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    scroll_layout.addView(plot_view);
}
```

The plotview is not even showing up on the scroll view

If possible please take a look a my iphone version of the app its free. What im doing this for is plotting the sound on the scroll view. that way you can get a better sense of what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PlotView` has zero size, you need to implement [`onMeasure(int, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29) to determine the size it should need for drawing as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).

You might also need to set some [`LinearLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) for it since you're adding the view to the `LinearLayout` through code.

Comment: i checked out this link http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LabelView.html i had to copy over the methods onMeasure and its requriements thank you Zharf